# Citations in separate tex file from bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, citing, natbib

I'm compiling a thesis where the main TeX file contains all my preamble declarations before including the thesis chapters as individual TeX files.  I'd prefer, however, to have a single bibliography at the end of the thesis but before any appendices.  However, when I try to do this none of my citations appear correctly in the chapters, i.e. they are replaced with "?", even though they all appear in the bibliography.

I discovered the `xcite` package, which I've attempted to use to solve this problem but haven't got it working correctly.  Probably a simple misunderstanding on my part of how to implement it.

The main file creates the main thesis from several chapters and the bibliography:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[authoryear,comma,nonamebreak,round,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{xcite}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\externalcitedocument{Chapter1}
\externalcitedocument{Chapter2}
...
\externalcitedocument{Chaptern}
\externalcitedocument{Appendix}

\begin{document}
    \include{Chapter1}
    \include{Chapter2}
    ....
    \include{Chaptern}

    \bibliography{Bibliography}

    \appendix
    \include{Appendix}
\end{document}
```

And the each chapter or appendix only contains text content, i.e. no preamble or `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` commands.  Citations within the text are made in the format:

```
...as found in \citet{Smith2013}...
```

I've tried moving `\externalcitedocument{Chapteri}` to the ith. chapter TeX file but it made no difference.  I'm using WinEdt7 PDFTeXify to compile my document and JabRef to create the bibliography.

It seems like such a straightforward action that I can only assume I've not used `xcite` correctly.

Comment: It should just work with `\include` and `\cite`. Of course if you have `\inclueonly` set you will need to do a run without that so everything picks up. have you run latex, bibtex latex the usual reason for getting `?` is you haven't run the full sequence of commands. Impossible to say without a working example.

Comment: I've tried running latex, bibtex, latex and it makes no difference. In fact I think that's what PDFTeXify does with one command.  And I'm not using `\includeonly`.

Comment: @JonathanAllen Are you using a thesis template from a university or crafting one on your own?  I can point you to a pre-made template from my grad school that you can play with as you so choose...

Comment: You are using `xcite` incorrectly in the sense that it was not designed for doing what you are trying to do.  (You are trying to do something much simpler, which standard `LaTeX` can handle just fine on its own, as @Kurt has shown in his answer.)

Comment: @BoZiffer My university are reasonable strict on the look of the thesis, therefore I've crafted my own LaTeX template to fit their demands.

Comment: @jon Yes, so I see, Kurt's solution is great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to show you that `xcite` is not necceccary and how to build an MWE for your problem please check the following MWE (with commented `xcite`). It includes with package `filecontents` three chapter files and a bib file. If you copied this MWE into file `mwe.tex` then `\jobname` becomes `mwe`.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{testxcite1.tex}
\chapter{Chapter One}
Text \cite{adams} 
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{testxcite2.tex}
\chapter{Chapter Two}
Text \cite{companion}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{testxcite3.tex}
\chapter{Chapter Three}
Text \cite{adams} \cite{companion}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{companion,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year       = {1994}
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\listfiles   % to show used packages and versions
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[authoryear,comma,nonamebreak,round,sort&compress]{natbib}
%\usepackage{xcite}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
%\externalcitedocument{testxcite1}
%\externalcitedocument{testxcite2}
%\externalcitedocument{testxcite3}

\begin{document}
\include{testxcite1}
\include{testxcite2}
\include{testxcite3}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Compile this MWE with latex, bibtex, latex, latex and you will get a pdf file and four warnings, coming from package `filecontents` (they are okay and can be ignored).  If you have  still `?` instead of a correct citation there is something other wrong with your system or way to build the pdf file.

Comment: Great, that's fixed the problem, both the MWE and my document itself work perfectly now - I just need to find an excuse to cite the Hitchiker's Guide somewhere in my thesis...